# How can I do multiple data is added to the array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, segue

select multiple in tableview, After only single data is added to the list

how can I add multiple data to in array?

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toGrafikVC" {
        let giden = segue.destination as! grafikVC
        if let gidenIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        giden.GelenDersIDArray.append(dersIDArray[gidenIndexPath.row])
        giden.gelenAd = dersAdiArray[gidenIndexPath.row]

        }
    }
}
@IBAction func kaydetButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toGrafikVC", sender: nil)
}
```

[Multiple Select in tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGXC3.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uRaa.png)

Comment: Use `indexPathsForSelectedRows` instead of `indexPathForSelectedRow` and use a for loop to iterate...

Comment: @Larme Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'IndexPath'

Comment: Because you didn't do correctly the for loop... `for anSelectedIndexPath in self.tableView.indesPathsForSelectedRows {gident.GelendersIDArray.append(dersIDArray[anSelectedIndexPath.row]); giden.gelenAd = dersAdiArray[anSelectedIndexPath.row]}`?

Comment: okey thx this worked